# New 3TB seagtae internal hard disk hangs after inactivity period

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have two interal seagate 3TB hard drives and 5 external usb drives.

Now wvery time i try to move mouse after some inactivity peroid. my system hangs and i ahve to wai for 2-3 minutes to get going.

System sometime becomes slow

I has been right from fresh install

What should i do

Comment: Sounds like one of the drives is a "Green" drive.  I would figure out which one it is and replace it.  I would disconnect all the external usb drives to eliminate those.  I assume they are hdds not flash.

Comment: go to the power options and disable the HDD shutdown to save power.

Comment: what are green drives and also i ahve installed all OS on it. can't i fix the problem now without replacing them

Comment: green drive = slows 5400rpm drives with lower power consumption. Have you tried my suggestion?